# Bootstrap/Rails navbar won't close when it is collapsed

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've looked at the other solutions here on Stack Overflow, but none of them seem to work. Any help is appreciated. The collapsed navbar will open, but when I tap on the button to close it, it just flickers and remains open.

Here is my navbar code:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">

<!-- Title -->


<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">

  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

</button>

<!-- Additional navbar items -->
<div id="navHeaderCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navHeaderCollapse">
  <!--                      pull-right keeps the drop-down in line -->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

    <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><% yield (:home)%><%= link_to "Home", root_path%></li>
    <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(services_path) %>"><% yield (:services)%><%= link_to "Services", services_path%></li>
    <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(careers_path) %>"><% yield (:careers)%><%= link_to "Careers", careers_path%></li>
    <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(contact_path) %>"><% yield (:contact)%><%= link_to "Contact Us", contact_path %>
    <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(about_us_path) %>"><% yield (:about_us)%><%= link_to "About Us", about_us_path%></li>

  </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I noticed that you forgot to close your `<li>` in the fourth list

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `//= require bootstrap on application.js` ? Try that.

Also, do you have:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

in `application.css.scss`?

Comment: Play with this:      http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h